# MSSQL doesn't work with incremeting or timestamp source connector

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to create source connector for my SQL Server tables, here's an example:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "config": {
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
      "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://REDACTED;databaseName=REDACTED",
      "connection.user": "REDACTED",
      "connection.password": "REDACTED",
      "topic.prefix": "test",
      "poll.interval.ms" : 2000,
      "table.whitelist": "dbo.Client",
      "mode":"incrementing",
      "incrementing.column.name": "Id"
  }
}
```

I'm getting following error, which doesn't say anything...

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of groups must be positive.
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectorUtils.groupPartitions(ConnectorUtils.java:41)
 at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector.taskConfigs(JdbcSourceConnector.java:148)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.connectorTaskConfigs(Worker.java:305)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.reconfigureConnector(DistributedHerder.java:997)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.reconfigureConnectorTasksWithRetry(DistributedHerder.java:950)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$900(DistributedHerder.java:110)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$17$1.call(DistributedHerder.java:963)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$17$1.call(DistributedHerder.java:960)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:270)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:219)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The same happens when I use mode timestamp with timestamp.column.name (column Modified with type datetimeoffset).

When I use mode bulk with a custom query, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `dbo.Client` exist with the column `Id`, using that exact casing? SQL Server is typically installed with a case-insensitive collation, but the connecting code apparently does care about case.

Comment: Yes, of course. The case of the column is as in the table.

Comment: What about just `Client`, omitting the schema? (Assuming your user's default schema is `dbo`.)

Comment: It's the same. There's no task assigned to that connector.